# Quicksort algoritm with Binary Search

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I'm solving a problem on Leetcode. It must be solved in O(n*logn) time. I've used the Quicksort and Binary Search, but it went wrong on 17th test case in 18.

My code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def sortArray(self, nums):
        self.quickSort(nums, 0, len(nums)-1) #=> [arr, low, high] it's for binary search
        return nums


    def quickSort(self, arr, low, high):
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        arr[mid], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[mid] # pick the mid as pivot every time
        if low < high:
            pivot = self.partition(arr, low, high)
            self.quickSort(arr, low, pivot-1)
            self.quickSort(arr, pivot+1, high)

    def partition(self, arr, low, high):
        i = low
        pivot = arr[high]
        for n in range(low, high):
            if arr[n] < pivot:
                arr[i], arr[n] = arr[n], arr[i]
                i += 1
        arr[high], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[high]
    return i `
```

More is [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-an-array/description/)

Comment: The testcase points to the issue. Trace it out for a small array of only equal numbers. How many operations does it perform?

Comment: Quicksort is **O(n²)** in worse case. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort  . So you  didn't solve it in **O(n* log n)**.

Comment: The question says *"without builtin functions"*; that would mean you would not be allowed to use `range` or `len` either.

Comment: @trincot: fortunately, they don't attempt to enforce that restriction. Of course, no-one would even think of cheating by using list's `sort` method.:-)

Answer (score 0):

Quicksort has a worst time complexity of O(²) and in the algorithm version you've chosen this worst case materialises when all values in the input are the same. You could try some other variants of quicksort, or you could first count the frequency of each number and then only sort the unique values:

```
    def sortArray(self, nums):
        d = {}
        for n in nums:
            if n in d:
                d[n] += 1
            else:
                d[n] = 1
        nums = list(d.keys())
        self.quickSort(nums, 0, len(nums)-1)
        return [n for n in nums for _ in range(d[n])]
```

This change to your `sortArray` will pass the tests, but its running time is not that great, nor its space usage.

I'd go for an algorithm whose worst case complexity is O(log). As the challenge also wants you to use the smallest space complexity possible, a standard merge sort is off the table (but some variants can go without extra memory). I will here suggest to use heap sort.

Below an implementation. I've also avoided the use of `len` and `range` so to take the instruction *"without using any built-in functions"* literally:

```
class Solution:
    def sortArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        def length():  # As we are not allowed to use len()?
            size = 0
            for _ in nums:
                size += 1
            return size

        def siftdown(i, size):
            val = nums[i]
            while True:
                child = i*2 + 1
                if child + 1 < size and nums[child+1] > nums[child]:
                    child += 1
                if child >= size or val > nums[child]:
                    break
                nums[i] = nums[child]
                i = child
            nums[i] = val

        size = length()
        # create max heap
        i = size // 2
        while i:
            i -= 1
            siftdown(i, size)
        # heap sort
        while size > 1:
            size -= 1
            nums[0], nums[size] = nums[size], nums[0]
            siftdown(0, size)
        return nums
```

Comment: [block merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort) can be implemented with no additional space, and is faster than heap sort, but it is complicated, for example [grailsort](https://github.com/Mrrl/GrailSort) .

Comment: I see. It is surprising that those rotations do not break the intended O(log) time complexity!

Comment: I deleted my prior comments to avoid "move to chat".  grailsort is based on [this article](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/35/6/643.full.pdf). Start with section 4, "stable in place merging".  Part of this is an efficient way to find unique values that get swapped to the front of the array. Since they're unique values, stability is not an issue, and they can be sorted later. Then the part of the array with the unique values is used as an internal buffer, merge operations include swapping to|from the front of the array. Optimized rotates are performed as needed.